# Can I run TensorFlow 2.0 on a Sagemaker notebook?

Tags: amazon-web-services, tensorflow2.0, amazon-sagemaker

I want to develop using Sagemaker notebooks but I want to use TF 2.0,

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a great question. To enable TF 2.0 on the SageMaker notebooks, you can go to the Conda tab (on Jupyter and not JupyterLab)  and select the tensorflow_p36 environment. On the bottom left, you can search "tensorflow" in the available Conda packages. There will be a TF2.0 option. Check that box, and the click on the right arrow, which will install TF2.0 into your tensorflow_p36 environment.

Restart any existing notebooks that are open.

Note: This works only with Jupyter and not JupyterLab.

Alex Chung
Senior Product Manager - AWS

Comment: Is it also available to medium services? I'm trying to do as you say for a "ml.t2.medium" notebook but I get a "gateway timeout" error and the tf.__version__ still shows 1.15.2

Comment: @Acalypha I have the same problem, even on a ml.t2.large.

Comment: A simple solution is to run a bash command in a cell to update tensorflow and then restart kernel, eg: `!pip install --upgrade pip && pip install tensorflow==2.2.0`